# C# Object property reference

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to "bind" the properties of two different instances of the same object?

For example;

```
class bar{
public int MyInt {get;set;}
public var foo {get;set;}
}
------------------------------------------
class MainProgram{
bar Bar1 = new bar();
bar Bar2 = new bar();
bar Bar3 = new bar();

//some logic here to decide which objects properties needs to get binded (in our case it could be Bar1 and Bar2)
}
```

I want that when I change bar1.MyInt or bar2.myInt, the other one gets modified to the same value aswell. The thing is that only MyInt property needs to be binded. So bar.foo should stay different for each instance.

I mean it could be done with some loops and such but there are many instances of the same object in the app. And the speed is important, so is there any way I could do this like one would do in c++ with references/pointers.

Comment: Do these values need to be the same for all instances of bar? Or do you need specific instances to be bound? I'd suggest looking at static variables and also something like the observer pattern depending on your use case: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/csharp/example

Comment: The code doesn't compile. You can't have a property of type `var` because its not a type. But if you want all instances of `bar` to share a property, declare it as `static`. Then the property belongs to the type and not to any one instance.

Comment: As an aside, I'd also strongly advise you to use conventional names even for demo code. The names `foo`, `bar`, `Bar1`, `Bar2` and `Bar3` are all distracting due to being unconventional. (Providing a [mcve] rather than code that doesn't compile and wouldn't demonstrate what you're discussing anyway is also a problem.)

Comment: To answer some questions, No it shouldn't be same for all of the instances, it should be bound for only specific instances. The var type used in bar class doesn't matter because   i need to bind only MyInt property, the "foo" variable should be independent for each instance. And sorry about non compiling code, thought this way could be more clear.

Comment: Dont forget to select a best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but it's going to take a lot of boilerplate code.

Step 1: Create a base implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
internal abstract class Notifier:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Step 2: Inherit the implementation in your data object and invoke `NotifyPropertyChanged` whenever a property is updated:

```
class bar:Notifier
{
    private int _myInt;
    public int MyInt
    {
        get=>_myInt;
        set
        {
            _myInt = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _foo;
    public string foo
    {
        get=>_foo;
        set
        {
            _foo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3 (optional but saves you some work): write an extension method allowing you to (more easily) invoke callbacks on `PropertyChanged` events for objects that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
internal static class Extensions
{
    public static void BindProperty(this INotifyPropertyChanged viewModel, string propertyName, Action changeAction) 
    {
        viewModel.PropertyChanged += (p, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == propertyName) changeAction();
        };
    }
}
```

Step 4: Define your binding behavior between two instances of `bar`:

In the bar class:

```
public void Bind(bar twin)
{
    //whenever twin.MyInt changes, update our value as well
    twin.BindProperty(nameof(MyInt), () =>
    {
        _myInt = twin.MyInt;
    });

    //whenever twin.Foo changes, update our value as well
    twin.BindProperty(nameof(foo), () =>
    {
        _foo = twin.foo;
    });
}
```

In your main program bind the two instances to each other:

```
public static void Main()
{
    bar Bar1 = new bar();
    bar Bar2 = new bar();


    Bar1.Bind(Bar2);//property changes on Bar2 now update Bar1
    Bar2.Bind(Bar1);//property changes on Bar1 now update Bar2
}
```

Note: This approach has its limitations. The biggest is that property changed events will not "chain", meaning if I bind a 3rd `bar`, `Bar3`, to `Bar2` (but not `Bar1`) and I update a property on `Bar1`, `Bar 3` will not update its matching property. In order to twin all three you would have to link each `bar` to each of the other two `bar`s. Of course, there are workarounds:

Is it some small subset of `bar`s that you need to bind to each other? You can create all the connections programatically:

This relies on the `NotifyPropertyChanged` boilerplate code

```
    public static void BindMany(params bar[] bars) => BindMany(bars);

    public static void BindMany(IEnumerable<bar> bars)
    {
        foreach (var bar1 in bars)
        {
            foreach (var bar2 in bars)
            {
                if (bar1 != bar2) bar1.Bind(bar2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
public static void Main()
{
    bar Bar1 = new bar();
    bar Bar2 = new bar();
    bar Bar3 = new bar();
    bar Bar4 = new bar();
    bar Bar5 = new bar();

    BindMany(bar1, bar2, bar3);//bars 1-3 now always share the same property values
    BindMany(bar4, bar5);//bars 4-5 now always share the same property values, but the values can be different from bars 1-3
}
```

As an aside, I've been programming for about 10 years, profressionally for 3, and I have NEVER encountered a situation where I needed to do this. It is extremely likely that your problem could be solved without binding properties in groups of objects. What is your use case?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. But I will need to bind more than two instances so,  what would be the workaround for such case? Or is there a better solution than PropertyChanged event?

Comment: @OguzHan I've updated my answer (at the bottom) to provide some solutions to your problem

Comment: Thanks it is really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a code smell. I don't know why you want it to behave that way but I would reconsider this kind of class design.

If you still want the same value shared by all the instances and don't want to use a static property then wrap `MyInt` inside a ref type and use that ref type as a property in your `bar` class.

```
    class Wrapper
    {
        public int MyInt {get;set;}
    }
        
    class bar
    {
        public Wrapper MyWrapper {get;set;}    
        public var foo {get;set;}
    }
    
    class MainProgram
    {
        Wrapper shared = new Wrapper();
        shared.MyInt = 10;

        bar Bar1 = new bar();
        Bar1.MyWrapper = shared;

        bar Bar2 = new bar();
        Bar2.MyWrapper = shared;

        bar Bar3 = new bar();
        Bar3.MyWrapper = shared;

        shared.MyInt = 20; // Affects all three objects
    }
```

Comment: You are probably right about the code smell, but the example you provide is very bad, because you need to make 3 assignments to update a bound variable ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Agreed. This is just an idea to get things going. I didn't mean to provide a production ready code. I don't make property setters public. As long as number of assignments are concerned, that can be done in a loop or ideally passed in constructor.

Comment: Yeah, it felt like a bad design but I wanted to see if there is a good workaround.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a built-in mechanism to "bind" properties of two objects, but there are different ways to do that, depending on your use case:

- Make the property (or the field behind it) `static` so that it's shared by *all* instances.
- Add an event (or use `INotifyPropertyChanged`) when the property changes (and add code to the setter to trigger the event) and have the second instance subscribe to that event.